# Can you apply non-unitary operators to a qubit?

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, quantum-information, schroedinger-equation, unitarity

I am wondering if it is possible to apply continuous, invertible transformations to a qubit which are not linear, i.e. not elements of $U(N)$ where $N=2^n$ where we have $n$ qubits.

Consider $n=1$. Then $c_0|0\rangle+c_1|1\rangle \in S^3$ since $|c_0|^2+|c_1|^2=1$. We could also let $\mathcal{V}=\mathbb{C}^2$ and consider the state space to be the projective Hilbert space $P(\mathcal{V})\cong \mathbb{CP}^1 \cong S^2$.

The usual Pauli, Hadamard, and phase-shift gates are order 2, 4, 8. They're unitary operators, and homotopic to the 2x2 identity matrix in $U(2)$.

I'm aware that states must evolve according to the Schrödinger equation and be of the form $exp(i\hbar H t) \in U(N)$ where $H$ is a Hamiltonian.

However, can we not consider an operation on a qubit which is a map $f:S^3 \rightarrow S^3$, or $g:S^2 \rightarrow S^2$ which has degree $\ne 0,1$? For example, take the suspension or double suspension (in the sense of Freudenthal) of the map $f_k:z \mapsto z^k$ on $S^1$. This map is non-linear, but its nonlinearity is that of a polynomial of degree $k$.

By analogy, it is "not possible" to have a bit which is in the state "2" in a classical computer, only 0 or 1. Well, once you discover that the bit is actually just a voltage $V$ beyond a certain threshold, you can "overclock" the bit and run it at $2V$ or $3V$, and store more information.

Comment: If you don't ignore the global phase, there are mathematical non-unitary transformations on a single-qubit  which might be what you're looking for...?  They can continuously take a known state (with an irrelevant global phase) to a range of possible states (depending on the actual global phase) and then eventually back to a known state, where the global phase again becomes irrelevant.  Analogous to pure->mixed->pure, which is what non-unitaries do.  They're invertible, too.  If this is falls within the scope of what you're asking about, let me know and I'll write more details.

Comment: @KenWharton This certainly falls in the scope of what I'm asking about; I'd be grateful for more details. My QED is a little rough, but my understanding is there's a $U(1)$ action on spinor states leaving the Lagrangian invariant. Here, we can see it, right? The "global phase" is just the $U(1)$ fiber over $S^2$ (the pure states) giving the "mixed states" as $S^3$. My map is continuous, invertible, probability preserving taking pure-->pure ($S^2\rightarrow S^2$) or mixed-->mixed ($S^3\rightarrow S^3$). It seems like the "sphere wrapping" map on pure states doesn't depend on phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the transformation I mentioned in my comment.  Most of the below claims are easily checked, but here's the [published reference](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8113/48/23/235302).

Before the global phase is removed from a qubit, it is a unit vector in $S^3$, not $S^2$.  This is equivalent to a unit quaternion, $q$.   Recall that with quaternions, order of multiplication matters.

(Aside: Formally the procedure to remove the global phase is a Hopf fibration, but this is a little suspect in this context, since you can't smoothly remove a phase from a 3-sphere.  A 3-sphere has a different geometry than a circle mapped to every point of a 2-sphere.)

The simplest map from a (phased) qubit to a quaternion is just $$(a+ib)|0>+(c+id)|1> \to a + bi + cj+ dk=q$$  Evidently, normalizing the qubit is the same as demanding a unit quaternion $|q|=1$.

The space of all unitary operations on $q$ corresponds to a right-multiplication by another unit quaternion $U$; $$q'=qU$$  Any possible unitary transformation corresponds to some $U$.

But there is another entire family of continuous, invertible transformations: the left-multiplication sector.  Some very special left-multiplications, by the unit quaternion $exp(i\phi)$, don't do anything except for adjust the global phase of the original qubit.  But every left-multiplication not of this form is equivalent to a non-unitary transformation.

One interesting (continuous, invertible) transformation is $$ q' =  e^{ \,j\phi} q.$$  For values of $\phi$ between 0 and $\pi/2$, the resulting qubit actually depends on the global phase of the original $q$.  If you didn't know the original global phase, this would look like a mixed state.  But the information hasn't been lost to the environment; it's all there.  Evidently a left-multiplication of  $ e^{-j\phi}$ would recover the original state.

To prove this is a non-unitary transformation, consider $\phi=\pi/2$, or $q'=jq$.  Now this operation is equivalent to the non-unitary time-reversal operator (it flips the original spin state to the opposite state, no matter where it starts).  You'll notice that doing this twice gives you the expected $j^2=-1$.

There are other families of such transformations as well; any left-multiplication *not* of the form $exp(i\phi)$ will do the trick.  Would be fun to find some use for these, but as the other answer noted, there is nothing in the formalism of quantum theory that would make one think that these were possible to actually perform.

Answer (score 0):

Experimentally, no you can't do any of what you describe as it seems nature has chosen linear unitary evolution. Although you can view measurements and open systems asobeying non-unitary evolution, although I'm not sure that's what you're looking for.

Nonetheless, you can study math of whatever you like, Scott Aaronson did go through and look at what results when you imagine Quantum mechanics based on the $n$-norm instead of the 2-norm. Link below:

https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/island.pdf

Comment: Right, it seems "nature" has chosen linear, unitary evolution. This is not a measurement, but rather a unary operation on a system which is a single qubit. This operation is invertible, continuous, preserves probabilities, and non-linear of degree $k$. I guess I'm wondering *why* we have to use linear maps, or if that's just a side-effect of the model.